# Cross-Origin PATCH and DELETE requests blocked by Spring Boot application, but not GET requests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cors, patch

I have the below security configuration in my Spring-Boot app at the moment. This is the standard stuff I've found online to allow all CORs requests (there are a lot of other configurations online that I've also tried).

These work fine for GET requests, however PATCH and DELETE requests are still being blocked due to CORs policy. Has anyone experienced this before?

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().configurationSource(request -> new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use addAllowedMethod to add additional method in default allowed methods(GET, HEAD, POST)

```
CorsConfiguration corsConfig = new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues();
corsConfig.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.DELETE);
corsConfig.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.PUT);

http.cors().configurationSource(request -> corsConfig);
```

Answer (score 0):

Right, so I fixed this with the below configuration, however there is a caveat to it: I'd tried this before, however I the first import suggestion for CorsFilter was not the correct one (org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter). This time, I imported the second instead (org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter) and this now works.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable();
    }
    
    @Configuration
    public class CorsConfig {

        @Bean
        public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
            UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
            CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
            config.setAllowCredentials(true);
            config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:3000");
            config.addAllowedHeader("*");         
            config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
            config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
            config.addAllowedMethod("PATCH");
            source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
            return new CorsFilter(source);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the global support for `CORS` by creating the following bean

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*");
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On more recent versions of Spring Security if you look at the CorsRegistration allowedMethods() you'll see

```
/**
 * Set the HTTP methods to allow, e.g. {@code "GET"}, {@code "POST"}, etc.
 * <p>The special value {@code "*"} allows all methods.
 * <p>By default "simple" methods {@code GET}, {@code HEAD}, and {@code POST}
 * are allowed.
 */
public CorsRegistration allowedMethods(String... methods) {
    this.config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList(methods));
    return this;
}
```

That by default only GET, HEAD, and POST are allowed.

Adding the additional methods or all ... which might look something like this

```
@Profile(value = { "LOCAL" })
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry
                        .addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedMethods("*") <-- This is the ticket
                        .allowedOrigins("*")
                ;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Should do the trick